# What is the best way to use golden feature in machine learning model?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

Let's say I have a classification model. And my job is to predict the correct class out of 30 different classes. The current accuracy is 70%.

The thing is: I *have to* consume another team's classification result which is 80% accurate. So I'm using their prediction label as a feature. I'll call it "golden feature". Let's say I'm aiming >80% accuracy with the golden feature.

Here is my current approach:

(I'm using Deep Learning.) I have several features and each feature has its own weight. I also created a weight vector for one hot vector (1 by 30) of "golden feature" and train all weights together. However the result doesn't seem to provide much.

I thought about the reason why and realized that the learned vector (30 by n, followed by n by 30, so that it produces 1 by 30) won't be that meaningful. They would be just positive numbers.
(Please yell at me if my reasoning is wrong!)

Has anyone faced the similar problem? Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.
The method that you suggest doesn't have to be Deep Learning approach.

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence arguably off-topic here; better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

You can have an ensemble modelling approach.

Here is what it would look like:

```
feature_1 ---- |         |  
feature_2 ---- | Model 1 | ---- output 1
feature_n ---- |         |

feature_1 ---- |         |  
feature_2 ---- | Model 2 | ---- output 2
feature_n ---- |         |

feature_1 ---- |         |  
feature_2 ---- | Model n | ---- output n
feature_n ---- |         |
```

Now, you build a meta model. A simple meta model might be a simple voting classifier (max vote from classifiers wins so all models have equal voting weight) or logistic regression (weighted voting). You can use neural network, random forest, or svm but it might be too complex model so consider using it depending on your particular problem and amount of data.

```
output_1 ---- |            |  
output_2 ---- | Meta Model | ---- Final Classification
output_n ---- |            |
```

In your case the "golden features" is just like output 1.

Have a look at this well written post for more details: https://blogs.sas.com/content/subconsciousmusings/2017/05/18/stacked-ensemble-models-win-data-science-competitions/

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you can do is try and supplement the first model with your second model. Have an intermediate predictor, whose only job is to predict weather or not the first model will produce the correct result. This intermediate predictor will take the same features as the original models. Since this is a binary classifier, you might get a high rate of accuracy from it. Then, use your own classification model instead of the original one if the confidence the intermediate model has is low.

Alternately, you can have two intermediate models, one for the original and one for your classifier. Then, take a weighted sum of the predictions, weighted by the confidence scores of the two intermediate models.